# How to re-export #%module-begin etc from scribble/text?

Tags: racket, scribble

I want a language like scribble/text but with some additional functions offered. This is what I've tried:

```lisp
#lang racket/base

(require scribble/text)
(provide (all-from-out scribble/text)
  hello)

(define (hello name)
  (format "Hello ~a!" name))
```

When I try to run a module written in this language, I get a message saying that there is no #%module-begin binding in the module's language.

I assume that scribble/text has a binding for #%module-begin, else how does it work when I use it as a #lang?

Maybe scribble/text knows that I am importing it using 'require' rather than as a #lang, and so I don't automatically get the #% macros? If that's the case, then how would I get them and re-export them?

Or is something else happening here?

Comment: What does “a module written in this language” mean, precisely? That is, what does the `#lang` line look like in the other module?

Comment: The original module is in a file called notebook/main.rkt, and the second file is written in it using the line "#lang notebook". What difference does it make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language for [`#lang scribble/text`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble-pp/text.html) and the library for `(require scribble/text)` are different modules. The library version doesn't provide `#%module-begin` or the other bindings from racket:

> When `scribble/text` is used via `require` instead of `#lang`, then .... it does not include the bindings of `racket/base` ....

The module-language [`#lang scribble/text`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble-pp/text.html) actually uses is `scribble/text/lang`. So you can fix your module-language like this:

```
#lang racket/base

(require scribble/text/lang)
(provide (all-from-out scribble/text/lang)
         hello)

(define (hello name)
  (format "Hello ~a!" name))
```

However, the module `scribble/text/lang` is undocumented, so use at your own risk.

Comment: It works, thank you. Is that a "rule" then, that language bindings are provided in a submodule called "lang", or does that just happen to be the case for scribble/text?

Comment: Just happens to be the case for scribble/text, not a rule